# Xamarin tesseract OCR returning bad output and gibberish

Tags: xamarin, ocr, tesseract

I'm using `Xamarin.tesseract` nuget package for my ocr. I have set up everything correctly, including the tessdata folder.
see the command below which is hooked up to a button click

```
    public ICommand OCRCommand => new Command(async () => await ocrcard());
    private async Task ocrcard()
    {
        try
        {

            var ocr = Resolver.Resolve<ITesseractApi>();
            if (!ocr.Initialized)
            {
                var initialised = await ocr.Init("eng");
                if (!initialised)
                    return;
            }
            var photo = await UtilityService.GetPhotoBase64StringAsync(false);
            var isReadSuccess = await ocr.SetImage(Convert.FromBase64String(photo));

            if (!isReadSuccess) return;

            var texts = ocr.Text;
            var words = ocr.Results(PageIteratorLevel.Word);
            var symbols = ocr.Results(PageIteratorLevel.Symbol);
            var blocks = ocr.Results(PageIteratorLevel.Block);
            var paragraphs = ocr.Results(PageIteratorLevel.Paragraph);
            var lines = ocr.Results(PageIteratorLevel.Textline);
            //DialogService.ShowAlertAsync(texts, "ocr text", "ok");
            //var ocrService = Tesseract.
            //s.Elapsed()
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

`await UtilityService.GetPhotoBase64StringAsync(false)` is a custom method that i wrote to get the photo from the camera using CrossMedia plugin.

I have tried all three options that `SetImage` provides.
I have tried passing in byte array, stream, and filepath. All three options return gibberish results.

This is the result in `ocr.Text`

"l *1 ' u 17\n\nm Hume \ vnsm Paguayom Rdtrentes Mamngs mew vuw\n\n(m A . .7 .7 ,7 r- w\n5* Calmnlﬁnny) v72 ~A A Aa\"% ::';:' :p‘EEEE‘él‘V A\nqacwv\n\n: V : , . . z 2 2 5:, V , ‘\nVmeatwamuM n I L, “5“! x z -A- Eff: v: Q 7 ‘ ”\nummm 4 m w Paragraph :3\nM\nJ I\n\n"

and this is the picture:
[image]

Comment: why are you using Base64?  That seems like a pointless step and the most likely cause of a problem

Comment: actually, looking at your data again, it does seem that its trying to parse the menu item text.  That may just not be a very good test image?  If you try a image or scan of a book page does it give better results?

Comment: I haven't used Tesseract in awhile, but I remember when I first started playing with it I had the same issue when I attempted to parse text from a picture of something on my monitor, I'm getting major deja vu lol. Try it with a book or something like Jason said, it will probably function fine.

Comment: So i have tried not using base64, just get the stream straight from the camera. I have tried and made sure 100% that the picture has nothing else but the testing text on the screen. I have also tried text on paper. I must be missing some important thing somewhere.

Comment: https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin/issues/35